# Image Hotlink Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hotlinking

I want to redirect any web page that uses my images to my website home page. Is this possible?

I know you can redirect to a custom image, but can I redirect the page using my image to my website front page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to redirect an image request to your home page, but it is NOT possible to redirect the page that requested that image to your home page (imagine the security risks that this would pose).